# choppy audio background playback by video on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, avfoundation, avplayer, core-audio

I'm facing a very annoying issue on iOS 12.1.3 with my iPhone XS Max and iPhone 7 Plus iOS 10.

I use some current video player apps from App Store the support for the video playback, the audio background playback. The videos can be added via itunes file sharing. it's all local in the app.

- Infuse
- nPlayer

I play music meditation video. The problem is that whenever the iPhone goes into idle mode (either by waiting, or by pressing the power button) or leave the app (to activate the audio background playback for video).

Then the sound stutters for 1 or 2 seconds. Which is very annoying, especially when you are in the middle of a meditation and need to hear instructions clearly.

Following are the steps to reproduce my problem:

1. Add video files with audio track to the app (Infuse or nPlayer) e.g via iTunes File Sharing
2. Activate the audio background playback
3. Play the video file
4. Go into idle mode or leave the app
5. The sound stutters for 1 or 2 seconds

Could you please help us with what the cause is. This is a general blocking problem for everyone. all video player apps for iOS have this problem.

Apps the only apple framework, like avfoundation, avkit, avplayer etc... use do not have these problems.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Maybe research on https://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: "all video player apps for iOS have this problem" Then it's not a Stack Overflow problem: it's an Apple problem. Delete this question and file a bug with Apple.

Comment: @matt but i want to know the cause, do you know it? what are the details? is it really iOS or apps?